# Multiple joins in a SELECT

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, rdbms

I have three tables.  These are joined by `ForeignKey` constraints so sqlalchemy knows how to join them.

I want to select the columns from all three tables:

```
select([a.c.x, b.c.x, c.c.x], a.c.a.between(10,20), [join(a, c), join(a, b)])
```

This generates the broken SQL:

```
SELECT a.x, b.x, c.x
FROM
   a JOIN b ON a.b_id == b.id,
   a JOIN c ON a.c_id == c.id
WHERE
   a.a BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

As can be seen, the table `a` is in the `FROM` clause twice!

How can you join three tables in a [select()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) statement using sqlalchemy?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQLAlchemy, but you might want to try [Queries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) instead

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is

```
    select([a.c.x, b.c.x, c.c.x]).\
        select_from(a.join(b).join(c)).\
        where(between(a.c.a, 5, 15))
```

And if someone want's to try it out here's the whole thing.

```
    import sqlalchemy
    from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Sequence,\
        ForeignKey, select, between


    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    url = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)


    a = Table(
        'a', meta,
        Column('id', Integer, Sequence('a_id_seq'), primary_key=True),
        Column('age', Integer),
        Column('name', String(20))
    )

    b = Table(
        'b', meta,
        Column('a_id', Integer, ForeignKey("a.id")),
        Column('value', String(20))
    )

    c = Table(
        'c', meta,
        Column('a_id', Integer, ForeignKey("a.id")),
        Column('title', String(20))
    )

    # Create tables
    meta.create_all(engine)

    # Fill with dummy data
    def add_data(age, name, value, title):
        q = a.insert().values({a.c.age: age, a.c.name: name})
        res = engine.execute(q)
        a_id = res.inserted_primary_key[0]

        q = b.insert().values({b.c.a_id: a_id, b.c.value: value})
        engine.execute(q)

        q = c.insert().values({c.c.a_id: a_id, c.c.title: title})
        engine.execute(q)

    add_data(12, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz')
    add_data(17, '111', '222', '333')

    q = select([a.c.name, b.c.value, c.c.title]).\
        select_from(a.join(b).join(c)).\
        where(between(a.c.age, 5, 15))

    print(str(q))
    # SELECT a.name, b.value, c.title
    # FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id
    # WHERE a.age BETWEEN :age_1 AND :age_2

    res = engine.execute(q)
    for row in res.fetchall():
        print(row)
        # ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz')
```

Updated answer, thx for the comment [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15721/will)!

Comment: `FROM a, b, c` is cartesian product!  You need `WHERE` or `JOIN`.

Comment: Oh, totally correct. Easy to miss with just one row/table :)  
I've updated the answer, please see if I'm better of now.

Comment: What if b and c have a relationship, or there is more than one relationship between two tables?

Answer (score 0):

give the below a go.

```
SELECT a.x, b.x, c.x
FROM *TABLENAME* a
JOIN *TABLENAME* b
ON a.id = b.id
JOIN *TABLENAME* c
ON a.id = c.id
WHERE
a.a BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```